# "str" is not a dataclass error with marshmallow and marshmallow-dataclass

Tags: python, types, marshmallow, python-dataclasses

Using python, I am trying to create data schema for my dataclasses using `marshmallow` and `marshmallow-dataclass`. I believe I have followed the docs, adding the decorator to my relevant dataclasses and `NewType`s to my fields that are not standard python objects. However, I am getting an error before the program even loads.

The error relates to a `str` not being a dataclass and I have no idea how the decorator is processing a string instead of a dataclass.

I am sure I have missed something simple, so apologies in advance if that is the case.

A summarised version of the code is:

```
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass as m_dataclass, NewType

ProjectileDataType = NewType("ProjectileDataType", Any)

@m_dataclass
class ProjectileData:
    Schema: ClassVar[Type[Schema]] = Schema

    # what created it?
    skill_name: str = field(default="None")

    # what does it look like?
    sprite: str = field(default="None")
```

defintions.py : https://pastebin.com/tHnVE2Gc
Error traceback: https://pastebin.com/htuqhKSU
Docs: https://github.com/lovasoa/marshmallow_dataclass , https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: Please don't use pastebin. Copy everything needed in your question.

Comment: I added a minimum example so that people don't need to check the pastebin but it is there to add full context. It's too big to paste into the post so would you recommend removing it instead?

Comment: Confronted with a similar situation, I found [a bug report on `marshmallow-dataclass`](https://github.com/lovasoa/marshmallow_dataclass/issues/13), indicating that there seems to be some conflict with `from __future__ import annotations`.

Removing this statement solved my situation; maybe you are in the same situation?

Comment: Have you found the solution?